# PHP - need an assits with __construct()

Tags: php, oop, session, construct

So I have this PHP code that I don't get

```
public $user = 'guest';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->user = (isset($_SESSION['user'])) ? $_SESSION['user'] : 'guest';
}
```

Can anyone please explain the above code , and is there any chance that I can change the session value without accessing the server-side ?

Comment: *I can change the session value without accessing the server-side* PHP  executes on server side

Comment: @splash58 yeah,but is there anything that I can do like adding cookies to make changes here in this situation ?

Comment: Are yo starting session ?

Comment: @splash58 yes, but not before this code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incoming request is being handled by script on server (it's a PHP as splash58 pointed out)

__construct() creates new objects, and inside it's decided if there is no `user` already set inside session ($_SESSION superglobal array), it injects 'guest' value into `$this->user`.

It's basically saying "if user did not log in, he's a guest".

You cannot change $_SESSION contents from frontend, this is done on server-side, so you have to modify PHP script to apply changes.

Edit:
for clarification, what you see inside constructor is ternary operator. Documentation here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary